# How to use rowwise with do function with if else of ifelse?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data frame which contain column, which is list.

data frame contain json reponse as column, and second column is list which is converted from JSON using following code.

```
vectorize_fromJSON <- Vectorize(fromJSON, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
z <- vectorize_fromJSON(data_df$json_response)
```

I am using rowwise with do function to extract information for list.

However, I am not able to use if with it.

Working code

```
t <- data_df %>% rowwise %>% do(
   test = class(.$json_list$cbas$dslscc)
)
```

I want something like as follows:

```
t <- data_df %>% rowwise %>% do(
     test = ifelse(class(.$json_list$cbas$dslscc)=="list", TRUE,    
     .$json_list$cbas$dslscc)
)
```

following is error:

> Error in
>   .$json_list$clear_bank_attributes$days_since_last_successful_check_cashed$nil
>   :    $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Can you show us some rows of the data_df? You can use dput(head(data_df,6))